# hm-swipe not working in angular-hammer module?

Tags: angularjs, swipe

Im trying to do a simple swipe ( do some action when it occur ), and nothing seems to work.

```
 function someFunc(){
         alert('do swipe');
    } 

<div hm-swipe="someFunc()">

</div>
```

If i change to hm-tap all seems to work properly, what can be the cause of this?

Comment: I also I am having this issue. I cannot get the hm-swipe-* to work but hm-tap does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swipe you need to drag it quickly, otherwise it will be a dragged event.

[see here the demo.](http://monospaced.github.io/angular-hammer/)

Comment: The screen is small, and i need a swipe up gesture to do something, right now it doesnt handle itself very well, perhaps the screen size? or changing some thing in the options?